# Implicit conversion from varchar to Varbinary how to?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I got the following error trying to convert from a varchar to varbinary..

> Implicit conversion from data type
>   varchar to varbinary(max) is not
>   allowed. Use the CONVERT function to
>   run this query.

and this is the alter command that I tried.

```
alter table foo Alter column bar varBINARY(max)
```

So how do I use the convert function for something like this? I did a bit of searching via google and had no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: This seems like it would be make more sense on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yep...defo one for SO methinks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to rebuild the table.

Use SSMS designer to change the type: this will generate a script with CONVERT.